# Get the path to My Documents with Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Is it possible to retrieve the path to My Documents folder with Inno setup?

I tried to retrieve the path via registry

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', 'Personal', path);
```

But it returned: %USERPROFILE%\Mina dokument. When I tried to use it as install path it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inno Setup supports the [Shell Folder Constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm) `{userdocs}` and `{commondocs}` for this job.